# Getting values from server side and assigning to a JavaScript variable

Tags: java, javascript

I have String Array Value in `request` object and I retrieved it like the following,

```
<%
                                        if (request.getAttribute("categoriesList") != null) {%>
                                        <input id="categoriesList" name="categoriesList" type="hidden" value="<%= (String[]) request.getAttribute("categoriesList") %>"/>
                                            <c:forEach var="categoryName" items="${categoriesList}">
                                                <li><a onclick="getCategoryIndex()" href="#">${categoryName}</a></li>
                                            </c:forEach>
                                        <% }%>
```

this prints the value to `<li>` but I also have hidden variable and I want to assign the value to it,

```
<input id="categoriesList" name="categoriesList" type="hidden" value="<%= (String[]) request.getAttribute("categoriesList") %>"/>
```

but when I printed them using java script like the following,

```
var category= new Array();
        category = $('#categoriesList').val();
        console.log(category);


        for (var i in category) {
            console.log(category[i]);
            }
```

I get ,

```
[Ljava.lang.String;@f2bc8d rechargeWalletRequest.htm:182
[ rechargeWalletRequest.htm:186
L rechargeWalletRequest.htm:186
j rechargeWalletRequest.htm:186
a rechargeWalletRequest.htm:186
v rechargeWalletRequest.htm:186
a rechargeWalletRequest.htm:186
. rechargeWalletRequest.htm:186
l rechargeWalletRequest.htm:186
a rechargeWalletRequest.htm:186
n rechargeWalletRequest.htm:186
g rechargeWalletRequest.htm:186
. rechargeWalletRequest.htm:186
S rechargeWalletRequest.htm:186
t rechargeWalletRequest.htm:186
r rechargeWalletRequest.htm:186
i rechargeWalletRequest.htm:186
n rechargeWalletRequest.htm:186
g rechargeWalletRequest.htm:186
; rechargeWalletRequest.htm:186
@ rechargeWalletRequest.htm:186
f rechargeWalletRequest.htm:186
2 rechargeWalletRequest.htm:186
b rechargeWalletRequest.htm:186
c rechargeWalletRequest.htm:186
8 rechargeWalletRequest.htm:186
d rechargeWalletRequest.htm:186
```

I am supposed to get the value but it prints some thing else.

Please help to get this done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to assign a unique id to each of the input-hidden statements.  Something like this:

```
<%
    if (request.getAttribute("categoriesList") != null) {%>
        <c:forEach var="categoryName" items="${categoriesList}">
            <input id="${categoryName}" name="categoriesList" type="hidden" value="${categoryName}"/>
            <li><a onclick="getCategoryIndex()" href="#">${categoryName}</a></li>
        </c:forEach>
<% }%>
```

Then fetch all the elements with the name property in jQuery and iterate over them to fetch values.

Answer (score 1):

Tried recreating your scenario.. what actually gets into the hidden field is the hashcode (use the browser's developer tools to see it). try returning a List instead of String[] and then it will work fine.